# aws calling lambda on cloudwatch alarm - Only email lists for this account are available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

On `AWS` I'm trying to create a `cloudwatch` alarm that sends a notification to a `sns` topic that in turn triggers a `lambda` function that is subscribed to the topic, but have run into a bit of a snag in which my `lambda` is never triggered. I've followed several tutorials on how to do this, I've manually tested the `sns -lambda` connection and this is working as is attaching the notification trigger onto `cloudwatch`.

I've done this all through `cloudformation`.

I have also tried to configure it manually from the `cloudwatch` console and then noticed something strange. Underneath the `Send a notification to` select box as shown in the image below, there is a message which says `Only email lists for this account are available`. So I'm guessing from that, that somewhere in this account, there is a weird setting that needs to be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that CloudWatch requires the permission to publish to the SNS Topic.

More info on setting this up can be found here: [Notifying users on alarm changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Notify_Users_Alarm_Changes.html#:%7E:text=Preventing%20confused%20deputy%20issues)

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer:

1. Is the CloudWatch alarm actually in the "Alarm" state? Can you add 2 more notifications to be triggered by the "OK" and "Insufficient data" state respectively?
2. by reading the original post, SNS should have the right permission to invoke the Lambda function.

---

previous answer:

That is a general message, it has nothing to do with your SNS topic settings. I reckon it's meant to say only emails opt-in to that SNS topic will get emails.

---

Q: How does Amazon SNS validate a subscription request to ensure that notifications will not be sent to users as spam?

As part of the subscription registration, Amazon SNS will ensure that notifications are only sent to valid, registered subscribers/end-points. To prevent spam and ensure that a subscriber end-point is really interested in receiving notifications from a particular topic, Amazon SNS requires an explicit opt-in from subscribers using a 2-part handshake:

i. When a user first calls the Subscribe API and subscribes an end-point, Amazon SNS will send a confirmation message to the specified end-point.

ii. On receiving the confirmation message at the end-point, the subscriber should confirm the subscription request by sending a valid response. Only then will Amazon SNS consider the subscription request to be valid. If there is no response to the challenge, Amazon SNS will not send any notifications to that end-point. The exact mechanism of confirming the subscription varies by the transport protocol selected:

For HTTP/HTTPS notifications, Amazon SNS will first POST the confirmation message (containing a token) to the specified URL. The application monitoring the URL will have to call the ConfirmSubscription API with the token included token.
For Email and Email-JSON notifications, Amazon SNS will send an email to the specified address containing an embedded link. The user will need to click on the embedded link to confirm the subscription request.
For SQS notifications, Amazon SNS will enqueue a challenge message containing a token to the specified queue. The application monitoring the queue will have to call the ConfirmSubscription API with the token.
Note: The explicit “opt-in” steps described above are not required for the specific case where you subscribe your Amazon SQS queue to your Amazon SNS topic – and both are “owned” by the same AWS account.

Comment: I have successfully subscribed my lambda to the sns topic. So much so that if you manually send a notification from the topic console, the lambda gets triggered. The issues seems to be when cloudwatch alarm is set, either it is not calling sns or there is something blocking the sns topic from then triggering the lambda

Comment: did you add permission to your Lambda function to allow the SNS service to invoke your lambda?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: 1. Is the CloudWatch alarm actually in the "Alarm" state? Can you add 2 more notifications to be triggered by the "OK" and "Insufficient data" state respectively?

2. by reading the original post, SNS should have the right permission to invoke Lambda function.

Comment: I hade a similar issue but I was trying to send a SMS (text message) instead of lambda. Turns our I needed to force cycle the "in alarm" state a  few time before it kicked in.